# What is version library spark supported SparkSession

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql

Code Spark with SparkSession.

```
   import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
   import org.apache.spark.SparkContext 

   val conf = SparkSession.builder
  .master("local")
  .appName("testing")
  .enableHiveSupport()  // <- enable Hive support.
  .getOrCreate()
```

Code pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.cms.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>cms-spark</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>cms-spark</name>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>scala-tools.org</id>
            <name>Scala-tools Maven2 Repository</name>
            <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.databricks</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-csv_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-hive_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.3</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                        <phase>install</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>
</project>
```

I have some problem. I create code spark with SparkSession, iam get trouble SparkSession not find in library SparkSql. So iam can't run code spark. Iam question what is version to find SparkSession in library Spark. I give code pom.xml.

Thanks.

Answer (score 22):

you need both core and SQL artifacts

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>cloudera</id>
        <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-cloudera1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-cloudera1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need  Spark 2.0 to use [SparkSession](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/05/11/apache-spark-2-0-technical-preview-easier-faster-and-smarter.html). It's available in Maven central snapshot repository as for now:

```
groupId = org.apache.spark
artifactId = spark-core_2.11
version = 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT
```

The same version have to be specified for other Spark artifacts. Note, that 2.0 is still in beta and expected to be stable in about a month, AFAIK.

**Update.** Alternatively, you can use Cloudera fork of Spark 2.0:

```
groupId = org.apache.spark
artifactId = spark-core_2.11
version = 2.0.0-cloudera1-SNAPSHOT
```

Cloudera repository has to be specified in your Maven repositories list:

```
<repository>
   <id>cloudera</id>
   <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/</url>
</repository>
```

Comment: haii @Vitaliy Kotlyarenko, i can't find in maven spark-core_2.11 in version 2.0.0. i add in maven : <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
   <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.0</version>
  </dependency>
i get error, because i look in maven   <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>, Last version 1.6.1. So any solution?

Comment: as it was mentioned, you have to specify version **2.0.0-SNAPSHOT**, not **2.0.0**

Comment: hail  @Vitaliy Kotlyarenko, ok i get download jar spark_core_2.11 version 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT, iam success download jar. But i can't find import SparkSession. i try import org.apache.spark.SparkSession but iam get error. Can you help me?

Comment: did you download it manually or Maven resolved this from repository? It's not clear from your comment

Comment: i download from maven repository. But i find class SparkSession in import i can't find SparkSession.

Comment: my depedecies <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
   <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </dependency>, success, not error.

Comment: hail @Vitaliy Kotlyarenko, any from HortonWorks,? Because iam using Hadoop in Hortonworks. Thanks.

Comment: did you download jar file manually from maven repo? if so, you have ton install it into local repo

Comment: It is not `org.apache.spark.SparkSession`. It is `org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession`.

Comment: @zero323 i dont find org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession, so iam get error. Any solution?

Comment: Wondering if you found a solution to this. I'm also running into same issue but when I use the latest spark from maven repo it does not include SparkSession.scala within sql. I'm using Only thing I am able to find is: `<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-preview</version>
</dependency>`