# how to use spark 2.0.0 preview in java

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark, repository

i want to import libraries from spark 2.0.0 preview version,
but there is'nt any spark 2 in maven repository right now.
i used suggested solution in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37340382/6318657).
but it didn't work:
the error is:

```
    The POM for org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.2.11:jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
The POM for org.apache.spark:spark-mllib_2.11:jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
The POM for org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.2.11:jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE

The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.2.11:jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.spark:spark-mllib_2.11:jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.2.11:jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.2.11:jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
```

my pom file is looklike this:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: How does your pom.xml look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your pom.xml:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>asf-snapshot</id>
        <url>http://repository.apache.org/snapshots</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Answer (score 0):

`2.0.0-preview` is available at [Apache Spark Core 2.11](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.11). You may modify your pom.xml as follows:

```
<properties>
    <spark.version>2.0.0-preview</spark.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-yarn_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```