# object SparkSession is not a member of package org.apache.spark.sql

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hadoop2

I am trying to use the latest Spark api with SparkSession.

While i am importing the package, my eclipse is showing an error show in attachment.

I am using 2.10.6 scala compiler.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

[image: pom]
[image: code]

Comment: you **spark-sql** and **spark-core** versions are inconsistent. try using either cdh or apache.

Comment: @mrsrinivas and - they are both very old and therefore do not contain the new `SparkSeesion` - use 2.0.0 or later

Answer (score 5):

Your version specified in Maven is too old. [SparkSession](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession.html) is introduced in Spark 2.0. Your need to use Spark 2.0.0 or later to import it. The answers of question below may help you to configure the details:

[What is version library spark supported SparkSession](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37337461/what-is-version-library-spark-supported-sparksession)