# Not found value spark SBT project

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt-0.13

Hi i am trying to set up a small spark application in SBT,

My build.sbt is

```
import Dependencies._

name := "hello"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

val sparkVersion = "1.6.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-twitter" % sparkVersion
)

libraryDependencies += scalaTest % Test
```

Everything works fine i get all dependencies resolved by SBT, but when i try importing spark in my hello.scala project file i get this error 
**not found: value spark**

my hello.scala file is

```
package example
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._

object Hello extends fileImport with App {
  println(greeting)
  anime.select("*").orderBy($"rating".desc).limit(10).show()
}

trait fileImport {
  lazy val greeting: String = "hello"
  var anime = spark.read.option("header", true).csv("C:/anime.csv")
  var ratings = spark.read.option("header", true).csv("C:/rating.csv")
}
```

here is error file i get

```
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to C:\Users\haftab\Downloads\sbt-0.13.16\sbt\alfutaim\target\scala-2.11\classes...
[error] C:\Users\haftab\Downloads\sbt-0.13.16\sbt\alfutaim\src\main\scala\example\Hello.scala:12: not found: value spark
[error]   var anime = spark.read.option("header", true).csv("C:/anime.csv")
[error]               ^
[error] C:\Users\haftab\Downloads\sbt-0.13.16\sbt\alfutaim\src\main\scala\example\Hello.scala:13: not found: value spark
[error]   var ratings = spark.read.option("header", true).csv("C:/rating.csv")
[error]                 ^
[error] two errors found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 3 s, completed Sep 10, 2017 1:44:47 PM
```

Answer (score 2):

`spark` is initialized in `spark-shell` only

but for the code you need to initialize the `spark` variable by yourself

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("testings").master("local").getOrCreate
```

you can change the `testings` name to your desired name `.master` option is optional if you want to run the code using `spark-submit`

Comment: Thanks Ramesh,
One more thing to add here is that SparkSession only works with spark 2.0.0
so my build.sbt is updated now 

`import Dependencies._

name := "hello"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

val sparkVersion = "2.0.0"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion
)

libraryDependencies += scalaTest % Test`

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37337461/what-is-version-library-spark-supported-sparksession]

Comment: yes thats right . for older versions you need to create sqlContext

Comment: Ramesh there is one more thing i am stuck in right now i have tried using online help,
**value $ is not a member of StringContext**

Comment: `import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.sql.{SparkSession, SQLContext}
import org.apache.spark.sql._

object Hello  {
  val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local").appName("TV Series Analysis").getOrCreate()
  import spark.sqlContext.implicits._
  import spark.implicits._
  var anime = spark.read.option("header", true).csv("C:/anime.csv")
  anime.select("*").orderBy($"rating".desc).limit(10).show()
}`

Comment: thanks i am done here is new code file


`val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local").appName("TV Series Analysis").config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir","file:///c:/tmp/spark-warehouse").getOrCreate()
  import spark.implicits._
  var anime = spark.read.option("header", true).csv("C:/anime.csv")
  var ratings = spark.read.option("header", true).csv("C:/rating.csv")
  anime.select("*").orderBy($"rating".desc).limit(10).show()`

Comment: glad to hear that you sorted out the problem you had. yes $ would be identified when you use import sqlContext.implicits._. If the answer helped then please accept and upvote :)